# What does the "expression" condition type in Rapidminer mean

Tags: expression, branch, data-mining, rapidminer

I want to initiate an "if-then-else" operation with the branch function, if a certain attribute has the name analytics. I thought expression is the right condition type, but it won't work. My example:
condition type: expression
condition value: BW_T1_Tag == analytics

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using the rapidminer user forum for questions on the **usage** of rapidminer... this website is meant for *programming* questions.

Comment: Sorry! Is there a Rapidminder Forum on stackoverflow or do you mean a forum outside of this site? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and not quite used to it now

Comment: There is an rapidminer forum on the rapidminer homepage. That is where all the rapidminer users are.

Comment: Thank you for your support! I will post my question there!

Comment: There are other tools such as Alteryx and Tableau which have a similar visual method for creating tools to solve problems without the need to write software. In essence, they are programming environments that don't need a programming background to operate. There are plenty of examples of questions on Stack Overflow for these tools so RapidMiner should not be treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Assuming that `BW_T1_Tag` is an attribute and  "analytics" is the value you want to match, use

```
BW_T1_Tag == "analytics"
```

The value needs quoting.